# Getting all items from SharePoint 2010 with PHP5

Tags: php, sharepoint, soap

I'm getting root elements from sharepoint with following code:

```
$client->GetListItems(array('listName' => $listName, 'rowLimit' => 10);
```

And it works well. But now I want to query all items recursively with this code (adding queryOptions):

```
$client->GetListItems(array('listName' => $listName, 'queryOptions' => '<ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>', 'rowLimit' => 10);
```

But I'm doing something wrong. This code returns HTTP 500 from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, had to use SoapVar like this:

```
$xml = new SoapVar('<ns1:queryOptions>' . '<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes    Scope="RecursiveAll" /></QueryOptions>' . '</ns1:queryOptions>', XSD_ANYXML, 'ns1');

$client->GetListItems(array('listName' => $listName, 'rowLimit' => 100, 'queryOptions' => $xml))->GetListItemsResult->any
```